# How can i match this string?

Tags: python, regex

When i have a large string like: `XXX;XXX,2014-04-11 14:06:54,XXX,00:00:00`
Then the re.search is not matching any idea how to fix it?

```
line= "connect data::Adata::Bdata::XXX;XXX,2014-04-11 14:06:54,XXX,00:00:00data::Cdata::D12data::EFdata::end"

if line.startswith("connect"):
  if re.search(r'connect data::[^:]+::[^:]+::[^:]+::[^:]+::[^:]+::[^:]+::end$', line):
    print "OK"
```

Comment: XXX is plain XXX or can be any character?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are also matching the `:` characters between hours and minutes. Try this one:

```
    if re.search(r'connect data::[^:]+::[^:]+::[^:]+:[^:]+:[^:]+:[^:]+:[^:]+::[^:]+::[^:]+::[^:]+::end$', line):
```

Also, you can skip the first if check by using a caret `^` to match the beginning of a line:

```
if re.search(r'^connect data::[^:]+::[^:]+::[^:]+:[^:]+:[^:]+:[^:]+:[^:]+::[^:]+::[^:]+::[^:]+::end$', line):
    print "OK"
```

Answer (score 2):

This might be a simpler solution:

```
arr = line.split("::") 
if len(arr) == 8 and arr[0] == "connect data" and arr[7] == "end":    
    print "OK"
```

No regex needed.   You're not validating the contents of any of those things; you're just checking for a total number of tokens, a separator, and a start/end token.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't match because of the fourth `[^:]+` that doesn't match `:`.

Try to replace `[^:]` with `.+?`.